# Display file from URL

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am using Xcode to build and app that will display documents in an URL

Currently have this code that is not working:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let showText: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://url-is-here.txt")
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL : showText))
    view.addSubview(webView)
```

There are no compile errors, all it does is show a blank box.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **connected** web view in the `Interface Builder` with an outlet you declared in code.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add UIWebView to View.

2.Connect webview outlet using assistant editor and name your "webview".

3.UIWebView Load URL.

Try to check whether webview in the Interface Builder with Outlet you declared programmatically,Otherwise try connecting with webview delegate to view.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I am not certain what you are suggesting.  I am somewhat new to Xcode and having a hard time figuring out what code you are suggesting and where.  Am I to replace code?  Move it around?  Add some code?